# ServerBundle deprecation while using Symfony local server

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 4.4.2
When I run the server using the server bundle...

```sh
./bin/console server:run
```

...I get a deprecation warning:

```
User Deprecated: Using the WebserverBundle is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. The new Symfony local server has more features, you can use it instead.
```

So I installed the Symfony local server and now I'm using it:

```sh
symfony server:start --no-tls
```

However, the deprecation persists.
Why?

Comment: Just remove the bundle from config/bundles.php.  Or maybe use composer. The bundle itself is actually fine.  The deprecation message just means you can't continue to use it once you move to Symfony 5.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have included the WebserverBundle bundle in your project, but this bundle will be deprecated past Symfony 4.4. As Cerad explained, the bundle itself is fine and you can still use it for now, but it simply means that you won't be able to use it anymore if you update your project to Symfony 5.

If you don't use the bundle and want to get rid of the deprecation message, simply run the following command:

```
composer remove symfony/web-server-bundle
```